# Padding of 好みの潰さで味ゎぅ

Tags: transitivity

I'm trying to parse (put spaces between each word) the following sentence in the picture attached:

[image: Sentence]

I've tried Recognizing the Characters using an app and got this :

好みの潰さで味ゎぅ

I recognize that there are three kanjis here which i'm not sure about. And for the last two characters (wa and u) I don't know if it was supposed to be in the small version like that.

1) Firstly I want to verify that the results of the recognition  are correct according to the picture. Please cmiiw

2) Secondly, how does it supposed to be like if the sentence is parsed into separated words in japanese?

3) What is the correct romanized transcription of this sentence?

Regards

Sidenote : i'm a newbie learning japanese. Only 2 or 3 times I've posted here. Definitely Not an expert...not even a beginner..he

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second kanji doesn't look like 潰 but [農【のう】](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%BE%B2) which in 農家【のうか】 means farmer, but with a [water radical](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%B0%B5%20%23kanji) attached. [濃【のう】](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%BF%83) is the character you're looking for which has nothing to do with farming or agriculture but is pronounced the same, and means dark in color, thick or concentrated.

It can also be  an i-adjective, 濃い【こい】.

Since さ is used right after 濃, which can be used to [nominalize adjectives](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/complete/more_amounts#Expressing_degree_with), I think it's 濃さ【こさ】 not 濃【のう】.

[の between two nouns](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/nounparticles#The_particle) - XのY- usually is like "X of Y" or "X's Y" depending on what the context is.

[好み](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%BF) could be read このみ, meaning liking or preference, or よしみ meaning friendship, connections, intimacy.

[味わう【あじわう】](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%91%B3%E3%82%8F%E3%81%86%0A) is a transitive 五段【ごだん】 verb meaning *to taste*.

[で](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/particles2.html) can be used in various ways, but one I know of is with or by, or by way of, as in :

> バスで来【き】ました。

meaning (I) came *by* bus.

To summarize,

1) The second kanji is *incorrect*, but the 2 other kanji *are* correct. The last two kana characters are a verb suffix and should not be written using the small version.

2) The full sentence in Japanese is:

> 好【この】みの濃【こ】さで味【あじ】わう。

You wouldn't write Japanese with spaces between each word, that would be unnatural in Japanese.

If you did break the words apart as a learning tool only, it would be :

> 好【この】み　の　濃【こ】さ　で　味【あじ】わう

3) The Hepburn romanization would be
 *konomi no kosa de ajiwau*.

Anyways, 頑張って【がんばって】 in your quest of learning 日本語【にほんご】!

Comment: Thanks! A wonderfully structured answer,  very easy to understand and indeed very helpful..